# Is "half-byte" ever actually used as a term?

Tags: byte, bit

Okay, so if a byte is 8-bits, then a half-byte would simply 4-bits. And you could have a quarter-byte as 2-bits (though I guess, if anything, it'd be reffered to as a double-bit).

While this is consistent, would anyone be confused (or surprised) if I used the term? Obviously, it would be fairly easy for them to grasp what I was referring to, but is it actually a commonly used term?

Comment: 4-bits are commonly referred to as a "nibble".

Comment: I've never heard the term half-byte, but have come across [tag:nibble]s.

Comment: That honestly made me laugh. Is there a term for a two-bit number?

Comment: Not seen it referenced in a long time, but the term "nibble" has since long ago been used to describe 4-bit units. Probably more commonly encountered back in the heyday of smaller, simpler processors - like the 4004.

Comment: @KevinMills Semi-nibble. Not even joking. Apparently the English language doesn't have a word for eating a chunk of food smaller than a nibble.

Comment: I think "dibit" is used to refer to a 2-bit value.

Comment: @WilliamGaul That turns out not to be the case. According to Wikipedia, though I've never heard the term used in a computing context, 2 bits (binary digits, not the US currency) make up one crumb of information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information#Crumb

Answer (score 5):

I never heard about "half-bytes" or quarter-bytes - normally you just state the number of bits for stuff smaller than a byte, since usually the focus is on how many bits you are talking about (if you are storing flags you want to know how many of them you can have in your field, or, if you are storing super-small integers, you want to know how large they can get), not on the fact that it's that definite fraction of a byte.

*But*: as already stated in the comments, when you cut a byte in half, dividing the upper and the lower 4 bits, each half is usually referred to as *nibble*. This thing probably has a name since, in hex editors, you actually *see* and *work* with nibbles (the two hexadecimal digits used to represent each byte), so it makes sense to call them in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put [this out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information#Obsolete_and_unusual_units), because I did a little poking around and I can't believe these terms actually exist. Enjoy!

Oh, and to make this an actual answer to your question, nibble is the commonly-used term for 4 bits as everyone else has already said.

Comment: 8 over 12 have [citation needed], so I think they are used only in *very* restricted contexts (*if* they are actually used)... :)

Comment: Yeah, or they're a joke and Wikipedia editors haven't caught it yet :P Still pretty interesting though.

Comment: We definitely need a name for three bits, because three bits make one octal digit. My vote is for tribble.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, a "nibble" is the word for a half an octet (semi-octet). To add new info, 2 bits is normally referred to as a "semi-nibble" or sometimes "half a nibble".